# Is there a way I can remove the range of characters form CString?

Tags: string, visual-c++, mfc, erase

As we can use string.erase function in std::string to remove certain range of characters is there any function I can use to remove the characters.

For eg:

```
std::string string = "This is a test".
```

I could use

```
string.erase(2,(string.length()));
```

Is there any similar method in [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx)?

Thanks.

Comment: never used it, but it has `Left` and `Right` and probably also a way to concatenate those two portions

Comment: Looking up the methods for `CString` is a pain, because it has base classes `CSimpleString` and `CStringT` and the methods are scattered.

Comment: If you wanted to cut out instances of a certain term within your string you could use Replace and pass it the term to find and and empty string. That would basically cut out that term wherever it appears. Otherwise I would use a combination of Left and Right.

Answer (score 5):

There are [CString::Left()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300477(v=vs.60).aspx) and [CString::Right()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300592(v=vs.60).aspx) functions. The alternative to your code would be:

```
CString result = string.Left(2);
```

Or if you would like to remove characters in the middle, you can use something like this:

```
CString result = string.Left(removeStart) + string.Right(removeEnd);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. Take a look at [CString Extraction Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043(v=vs.60).aspx#_mfc_extraction_cstring)

Your code snippet can be achieved by

```
CString s = "This is a test".
s = s.Left(2);
ASSERT(s == "Th");
```

To remove a range of characters so to keep the first m and last n characters, you can do:

```
s = s.Left(m) + s.Right(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

`CString.Delete` perhaps?

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#delete